# ASP .NET Routing with Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-routing

Is it possible to add a general route for all pages, or do I have to register each route? I work on a .NET web forms project and I am using ASP .NET Routing.

Currently I am using this to register the routes:

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
} 

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
{ 
   routes.MapPageRoute("MainPage", "{param1}/{param2}/MainPage.aspx/{*pathInfo}", "~/MainPage.aspx"); 
}
```

Comment: How do you register your routes currently?

Comment: protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
 }

        void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("MainPage", "{param1}/{param2}/MainPage.aspx/{*pathInfo}", "~/MainPage.aspx");
 }

Comment: but I have a lot of aspx files, and I have to register each page in Global.asax

Comment: What about Attribute Routing?